# version update script for a script

Tags: php, web

I'm going to try making this easy to understand and hope it makes sense.

I have a PHP script / template and I want the end user to be able to know when I updated something, (eg. template change or a bugfix) and they can click a link to download the updated version from a remote host. I tried the scripts posted on
[PHP - How to check a script version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652964/php-how-to-check-a-script-version) and I sorta got this script working:

```
<?php define('REMOTE_VERSION', http://mysite.com/_client/client_name/update/version_check.txt');
    define('VERSION', '2.0.1');
    $script = file_get_contents(REMOTE_VERSION);
    $version = VERSION;
    if($version == $script) {
        echo "<div class=success> 
    <p>You have the latest version!</p> 
    </div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class=error> 
    <p>There is a update available!</p> 
    </div>";
    }?>
```

Well sort of... The .txt file on my remote server just has 2.0.1.  Since they are the same version (both 2.0.1), it should read "You have the latest version!" In this case it says "There is a update available!" no matter what number I put in.

```
define('VERSION', '2.0.1'); //in php above
```

> 2.0.5  //in .txt file on remote server

Says same things as it should because on the remote server is showing a new update (eg. 2.0.5).  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly `var_dump($script);` to see if the output is `string(5) "2.0.1"` (string with 5 characters). Your txt file can have BOM in the beginning of the file or just space / new line at the end.

Comment: sorry i do know about php and whatnots just not good at it...and i dont understand what your saying there do i need to add var_dump($script); &  string(5) "2.0.1"  if so were at?

Comment: @Marlboroman213, Put `var_dump($script);` after `$script = file_get_contents(REMOTE_VERSION);` and tell us what you get?

Comment: @Starx that makes it say " bool(false)
There is a update available!" even when  changing the version number remotely

Comment: @Marlboroman213, this means that it is not readying the file properly. Make sure the file is readable.

Comment: @Starx there was no change when i made the txt file on remote server  read only '454' still says " bool(false) There is a update available!"

Comment: @Marlboroman213, can you open that file in the browser when opened separately?

Comment: @Starx  if your wondering if i can see the txt file directly ..yes i can using http://mysite.com/_clients/name/update/version_check.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a quote on the second part of the `define('REMOTE_VERSION', ...);` line. I added in the quote, and you also added unnecessary lines of code by reassigning the defined variable `VERSION` to a new variable `$variable`. This script should work; I've used something similar to this before.

```
<?php 
define('VERSION', '2.0.1');
$script = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/_client/client_name/update/version_check.txt');
define('REMOTE_VERSION', $script);
if(VERSION == REMOTE_VERSION) {
    echo "<div class='success'> 
<p>You have the latest version!</p> 
</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='error'> 
<p>There is a update available!</p> 
</div>";
}?>
```

Comment: i tried ytour way with the same results everythihg is set correctly but its not working

Comment: there is no error it just wont say "You have the latest version!" if both the versions in the above script and the .txt file on remote server are same no matter what i do... it keeps saying "There is a update available!"

Comment: @Marlboroman213 check out the difference [here](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=98e7p)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a typo, but there is an error at your constant definition.

```
define('REMOTE_VERSION', http://mysite.com/_client/client_name/update/version_check.txt');
                     // ^ Missing quote
```